# gmaps primefaces problems

Tags: java, primefaces, jsf-1.2

When I load the page, it shows the map and only shows a gray screen.  Display currently as the image. This is my code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:m="http://code.google.com/p/gmaps4jsf/">

<h:head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>

</h:head>

<h:body>


        <h1>Google Map</h1>

        <h:form>

           <f:view  contentType="text/html">    
               <p:gmap center="41.381542,2.122893" zoom="15" type="HYBIRD"
                style="width:600px;height:400px" />
           </f:view>

       </h:form> 
</h:body>
```

Comment: Could it be the typo in your code here that also appears in your webapp `type="HYBIRD"` should be `type="HYBRID"`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to define p:gmap outside and without f:view tag? I think also defining the

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true" />
```

is not necessary.